# trying to plot hline on pivots

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

ta,pivothigh and ta.pivotlow will plot labels on pivot points, but I would rather draw hlines on the pivot prices.  I tried modifying the standard script thus:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Pivot Lines", max_lines_count=500, overlay=true)
leftBars = input.int(50)
rightBars=input.int(50)
ph=float(na)
pl=float(na)

ph := ta.pivothigh(high, leftBars, rightBars)
pl := ta.pivotlow(close, leftBars, rightBars)

hline(ph, color=color.orange, linestyle=hline.style_dotted, linewidth=2)
hline(pl, color=color.orange, linestyle=hline.style_dotted, linewidth=2)`
```

But this is throwing an error. Any thoughts?

(I tried altering the code such that ph and pl variables are 'float', but that didn't solve the problem...)

I believe the issue is that hline can't accept series data. In that case, anyone have a better idea of how to solve the problem?

Comment: *this is throwing an error* is useless as a problem description. What *error* is happening? Is there an error message? If so, the **complete, exact error message** should be included in your post. You need to provide the details you have available if you want someone to help you. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work:

```
indicator('GT Pivot Lines', shorttitle='GT Pivots Lines', overlay=true)

lenH = input.int(title='Length High', defval=50, minval=1)
lenL = input.int(title='Length Low', defval=50, minval=1)

fun(src, len, isHigh, _style, _yloc, _color) =>
    p = nz(src[len])
    isFound = true

    for i = 0 to len - 1 by 1
        if isHigh and src[i] > p
            isFound := false
            isFound

        if not isHigh and src[i] < p
            isFound := false
            isFound

    for i = len + 1 to 2 * len by 1
        if isHigh and src[i] >= p
            isFound := false
            isFound

        if not isHigh and src[i] <= p
            isFound := false
            isFound

    if isFound
        line.new(bar_index[len], p, bar_index, p, color=_color, width=2, extend=extend.right)

fun(high, lenH, true, line.style_dashed, yloc.abovebar, color.lime)
fun(low, lenL, false, line.style_dashed, yloc.belowbar, color.red)
```